# how to start a semi?

Tags: starting

the wind is blowing another way but there is a fire near house. cleared all cars in the driveway but there is an abodoned semi parking near the house wondering how to start it. It should be like a car but im just making sure. I am not sure how the parking brake works either

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you have a key? Turn the key, ensure there is power. Press the start switch (should be a momentary button, in most cases). You'll need to ensure the air pressure is high enough (should be a range on the gauge). I believe you push the brake button to release the brake. Then shift like you would a car. Don't worry about the splitter.

Comment: very carefully....

Comment: Bail and leave it!!!! No vehicle is worth your life in a bush fire!!!

Comment: Do you have the make/model/year of the truck you are trying to move?

Comment: It looks like a Kenworth to me, but I cannot see anything that would tell me for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Should start similar to a car.  There may be a push button to start, but most trucks don't have that anymore.   The knob marked tractor will release the brakes as soon as their pressure builds up to around 90.  Drives similar to manual car. Leave the small lever on the shifter in the downward position.  Reverse is towards the steering wheel and then straight back for 1st.

Comment: Good luck with the fire.  I had in-laws that dealt with the fire in Colorado a few years ago.  Stay safe.